# Estimating the response variable distribution in bivariate simple linear regression

Tags: regression, marginal-distribution

So let's say I have a bunch of $IID$ samples $(X_n,Y_n)_n$ from some unknown distribution $p(x,y)$, where $Y$ is the response variable and $X$ is the explanatory variable.  And suppose I plotted these points and saw a pretty obvious positive linear relationship, (for instance maybe $X$ is amount of sunlight and $Y$ is sunflower height, or something like that).

Then suppose I wanted to try to get a good idea of what the distribution for $Y$ might be.  Well I could just look at the $Y$ coordinates from my samples and plot a histogram and then fit a curve to it, or something like that, but I believe that would only make sense under the assumption that the $Y_n$ are $IID$, when all I know is that they are identically distributed, and not necessarily that they are independent.

So instead what I do is plot the least-squares regression line $y=f(x)$ for my data, and then try to calculate the marginal distribution for $Y$:
$$p(y)=\int_{x\in\Omega}p(x,y)dx=\int_{x\in\Omega}p(y|x)p(x)dx.$$

Now what I do is assume there's some standard normal variability about my regression line, and so I set $p(y|x) = N(f(x),1)$.  However the problem in finding $p(x)$ is the same problem I have in finding $p(y)$, namely, my samples $X_n$ could very well not be independent.

Assuming I'm understanding the theory correctly, how do I go about resolving this?

**Edit**: Now I'm thinking maybe the $Y_n$ are independently sampled, but how would one go about proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_i$ are an iid samples from the distribution $p(x,y)$, then the $\{Y_i\}_i$ will be an iid sample from the marginal distribution $p(y)$.

To see this, write the joint distribution $p(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ as $$p(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=\int_{x_1\in\Omega}\cdots\int_{x_n\in\Omega} \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i,y_i)\ dx_1\cdots dx_n. $$

Then it follows that 
$$p(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\int_{x_i\in\Omega}p(x_i,y_i)\ dx_i= \prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i),$$
showing that the $\{Y_i\}_i$ are iid with distribution $p(y)$.